# Meaning of "closed up 7.6%"

Tags: meaning

> Chandler, Arizona-based Insys had no immediate comment. **Its shares closed up 7.6 percent** at $7.36 on the Nasdaq. [reuters](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-insys-opioids/u-s-joins-whistleblower-case-against-insys-over-kickbacks-idUSKCN1IF31M)

Hi, I am not sure what does "closed up 7.6 percent" mean here, especially "up".

Does it mean the shares end up increasing **by** 7.6 percent or **to** 7.6 percent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more a question about *terminology* than English.

In trading, stock exchanges have set trading hours. For example the New York Stock Exchange trades from 09:30-16:00.

When financial reports say "*shares closed at...*" it is referring to their value at closing time.

So in your example:

> Chandler, Arizona-based Insys had no immediate comment. Its **shares closed up 7.6 percent** at $7.36 on the Nasdaq

I understand that to mean that when trading closed, shares for Chandler were "up" (that is higher than when they began trading) **by** 7.6%.

To answer your last question: you would **not** write that shares went up *to* a percentage because that doesn't mean anything mathematically. A percentage is not an amount of money, so if I said something had "gone up to 7.6%" it is meaningless and you still don't know what it is worth. Saying "gone up by 7.6%" is a reference to its original monetary value.

I would say that grammatically it doesn't matter if you say "up by 7.6%" or omit the word "by" - but as we are talking about trading terminology the normal rules of English may not apply. I do not work on the stock market, but if your original quotation was lifted from a financial publication I would say that is normal to simply say "up 7.6%"